# swf file to html-css-js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flash

I don't know if stackoverflow is the correct place for this question. If not, feel free to move it in the correct site.

I have two swf files:

http://www.austintxgaragedoor.com/special-mail.swf

http://www.austintxgaragedoor.com/special.swf

My client wants to convert them to something so the text will be in the html code.
I thought to use two gif files. When the user hover the specific div then the second gif replace the first and gives the effect. The text will be positioned with css.
I am not sure if this a proper way to do it, or there is a better way.

What is your opinion?

Comment: If you use images/image-replacement the text won't be in the html, it'll be in the images, surely? **edited**, did you mean `background-images`?

Comment: If I had to to this I would try to do it the same way.

Comment: @David Thomas, the image will be inside a div and below another div with text, which I will position it relative with top:-xx; when the user rollover the image it will just change. After some research I find out that I can use the current flash, without position in over the flash with position:relative; I didn't know that I could do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could probably but this together using 3 gif files: 1 for the static image, 1 animated gif with the in-sweep, and 1 animated gif with the out-sweep... and use JavaScript/Jquery to switch between these images based on hover state. Static at first, sweep-in on mouse-over, and sweep-out on mouse-out.

This may be unwanted advice but if possible, I would recommend that you urge your client to allow you to just use a simple CSS hover and changing either basic styling or swapping a background image - which you can do in a couple of minutes. Your client may not be understanding that having this specific effect won't cause any more people to click on it.